# Chamar função PHP no onload da página

Tags: php, html

Quero chamar uma função PHP que esta no mesmo ficheiro. Tentei isto dentro do código HTML.

```
<?php select($dir, $base); ?>
```

E a minha função PHP:

```
function select($dir, $base){       
    $base_hndl  =   new SQLite3($dir.$base);                
    $requete    =   "SELECT id, title, start, end, description FROM \"event\" ORDER BY id DESC";
    $resultat   =   $base_hndl->query($requete);     
    $affiche    =   $resultat->fetchArray();

    echo "<br><label><b>ID: $affiche[id]</b></label><br>";
    echo "<label><b>Title: $affiche[title]</b></label><br>";    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível fazer isto diretamente.

PHP é uma tecnologia do lado do servidor não sendo diretamente acessível através do HTML ou Javascript.

Para realizar uma chamada PHP a partir do evento `onload`, o mais simples é colocar a função em um outro arquivo PHP e fazer uma requisição AJAX para este arquivo. Com a resposta retornada, em Javascript você deve atualizar o HTML para refletir os dados retornados.

Acredito que você seja iniciante, portanto há bastante para estudar aqui. Recomendo que olhe as páginas **em inglês** da Wikipedia sobre PHP, Javascript e AJAX apenas para ter uma introdução sobre o que se trata cada tecnologia.

Feito isto, recomendo que procure sobre a biblioteca jQuery, que facilita muito a vida na manipulação do DOM e na criação de requisição de requisições AJAX.

Tente então construir os códigos, e que caso encontre mais dificuldades, escreva questões descrevendo em detalhes os erros e dificuldades encontradas.

[Wikipedia: Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax)

[Wikipedia: JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)

[Wikipedia: PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

[jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Acho que um exemplo basico poderia ajuda-lo a entender.